# How Do I set a Teamcity Trigger on a Particular Folder for Git VCS trigger

Tags: git, version-control, triggers, teamcity

I would like Teamcity to Trigger a build when there is a gerrit change on a specific branch on a specific folder. I'm unable to achieve the same, any suggestions from all you experienced users out there is greatly appreciated.

Following is how my Structure looks like, I want the build to be triggered of both the Branch dev & Staging, any change under New/Folder/My_Content only and not on any other foder , file content

```
 - Branch dev
  --Repo
     * New/Folder/My_Content
     * Folder 2
     * Folder 3
     * File1.txt
     * File1.html
     * File1.log

 - Branch Staging
  --Repo
     * New/Folder/My_Content
     * Folder 2
     * Folder 3
     * File1.txt
     * File1.html
     * File1.log
```

This is what I have tried

```
VCS root name: my_root 

set on branches 

+:refs/(changes/*)
+:refs/heads/dev
+:refs/heads/Staging

VCS Trigger rules:
+:root=my_root:New/Folder/My_Content/**
Branch filter:
+:changes/*
```

The above rules always trigger builds on everything, on all the folders apart from the one I need.

And the second question I had was, Can I use parameters in the VCS Trigger rules.
Something as follows.

```
VCS Trigger rules:
+:root=my_root:New/Folder/%my_var%/**
Branch filter:
+:changes/*
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need to add **two VCS Roots** for the branches `dev` and `Staging` you want to trigger and **specify the file path** you need to trigger.
Detail settings as below:

- **In Version Control Settings Tab**, add two VCS roots separately:

  First VCS root name is `<repo URL>+:refs/heads/dev`, default branch is `refs/heads/dev`.

  Second VCS root name is `<repo URL>+:refs/heads/Staging`, default branch is `refs/heads/Staging`.

  Below is an example VCS root configuration:

  [image]

  For VCS checkout mode, you can select `Always checkout files on agent`, and select **Allow builds in the default branch**.
  [image]
- **In Triggers Tab**, set the trigger rule as `+:New/Folder/My_Content/**`.

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, I'll try this out, 
But I'm actually trying to use both the branches in a single vcs root, so that both the branches are monitored at the same time but only one branch is checked out based on the trigger when a change is detected, is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a slash after the repo root.

```
+:root=my_root:/New/Folder/%my_var%/**
```